# Is it possible to save a song "station" in Apple Music?

Tags: apple-music

When I play a song in Apple Music and select "Start Station" to begin an ad-hoc radio station based on that song, is there a way to capture the results for later, i.e. to replay the station or turn it into a playlist?

Or can I only return to the original song and hit Start Station again?

Comment: I just did a search for "Apple Music save station" and came across this... and then realized it's *my* question from five years ago.  Looks like finding the song in your history (or your library) and creating a station from it remains the solution. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I found to kind of do this:

Once you play a song and start a "station," that song will be saved to the "Recently Played" section of Radio. So if you want to start that "station" again later, just go to Radio, choose the song from the "Recently Played" section and the station will pick up again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 I noticed this, too. Might be the closest we'll get, but let's see if anyone else finds anything.